# SQL database doesn't recognize non English characters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create a application which uses a database but I need it to save data as Unicode...
I changed the types to nchar or ntext but still it saves my characters as question marks 
Any solution?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using parameterized queries?

Comment: I guess the problem isn't in the database but in the program. It's a bit hard to tell without any code at all.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: If you use ASCII fields, you'll get weird characters no matter the database. If you send ASCII strings to the database, you'll get weird characters. What database are you using, are the fields Unicode? What is your query? Do you use parameters or construct a query using string concatenation? Is your *source* data Unicode in the first place?

Comment: Post the table schema, the query and the code you use to execute it. It's impossible to give a specific answer like this, other than saying that all databases support Unicode

Comment: If your database is SQL Server, dont' use `ntext`. It's deprecated. Use `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the database that you're sending it unicode strings.

Using parameterized queries (which you should be for security):

```
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mycolumn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = "hello";
```

Using a straight query (please, for the sake of all things good, use parameterized queries):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES (N'hello');";
```

P.S. it's probably better to use nvarchar in the database as opposed to nchar as I believe nchar will pad your strings to the field length.

Comment: That won't help if the field is `varchar`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "I changed the types to nchar or ntext" that's not what the op said?

Comment: The OP hasn't provided any information. We have to guess. SQL Server isn't the only database that uses NCHAR, although it may be the only one to *not* use `NTEXT` because it's deprecated

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The OP provided that information, which a) suggests it's SQL Server. b) He's tried inserting data with the field as nchar and ntext, which means the problem is clearly client side and that he's already handling the database-side stuff. c) The logical conclusion from this is that he isn't telling SQL that the data he's sending it is unicode format.
---
I realise this is an assumption, but it isn't a bad assumption. If it's wrong and he's using some bizarre database engine then I'll happily update/remove my answer.